# Entries tag search:fieldtype=""

Tags: search, grid, ee5

According to the EE doc, within a channel entries tag you can search a grid field as long as the field color is set to "yes" for Include in search.

I have bot he Grid field and the individual column set to yes, but don't get results when I definitely should.
In the example below, there is a Grid titled "product_application" and one of 3 fields with the title "partno".

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="models" search:partno="={segment_3}"}
    <p>{title}-</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Has anyone run into difficulties with this?

Russ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `search` parameter in **Grid** you have to add `search` parameter in *grid fieldtype* not in Channel entries tag. You can get more information from below example. https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html#searchcolumn_name

```
{grid_field search:partno="search_value"}
    {grid_field:your_grid_field}
{/grid_field}
```

I hope this will works for you. Thanks!

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you.  I looked over that several times in the docs and completely mis-read what I needed to do.